# VB.Net COMException when trying to paste data from one excel doc to another

Tags: excel, vb.net, automation, excel-interop, comexception

As I've been building this Windows Form in VB.Net I've had one persistent error that i just can't seem to shake. I've been digging through google as best I can for an answer but haven't had any luck.

Basically what happens is when my app gets to the below Sub it will sometimes error out with a very unhelpful

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.dll
```

error but sometimes runs fine.

Here's the Sub in question;

```
Sub DriverSheet_Data_Transfer(XLAimApp As Excel.Application, XLAimWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet, XLAimWorkBook As Excel.Workbook, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Transfering Driver Information...")

    ' Define Driver Sheet Vaiables
    Dim XLDriverWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim XLDriverWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rowNum As Integer

    ' Open Driver Sheet
    XLDriverWorkBook = XLAimApp.Workbooks.Open(GeneratorForm.driverPath)
    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "{0} Succesfully Loaded...", driverPathLbl.Text)
    XLDriverWorkSheet = CType(XLDriverWorkBook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    ' Find total number of rows
    rowNum = 2
    While (XLDriverWorkSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value IsNot Nothing)
        rowNum += 1
    End While

    ' Filter DriverSheet Data by ID ascending
    XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A1:D" & rowNum - 1).Select()
    XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A1:D" & rowNum - 1).Sort(Key1:=XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A1"),
                                                      Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                                                      Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
                                                      Header:=Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes,
                                                      MatchCase:=False,
                                                      SortMethod:=Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin,
                                                      DataOption1:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal
                                                      )

    Try
        ' Select Data and Copy
        'Clipboard.SetDataObject(XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A2:D" & rowNum - 1))
        XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A2:D" & rowNum - 1).Copy()
        'XLAimWorkSheet.Paste(Destination:=XLAimWorkSheet.Range("R2"))
        XLAimWorkSheet.Range("R2").Select()
        XLAimWorkSheet.Range("R2:U" & rowNum - 1).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAllExceptBorders)


    Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        MsgBox("ERROR: Guess what? That one error that you can't figure out happened again. Ugh...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Stupid Error Strikes Again")
        ' Close Driver
        XLAimApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        XLDriverWorkBook.Close()
        releaseObject(XLDriverWorkBook)
        releaseObject(XLDriverWorkSheet)
        ' Close Aim
        XLAimWorkBook.Close()
        XLAimApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(XLAimApp)
        releaseObject(XLAimWorkBook)
        releaseObject(XLAimWorkSheet)
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Transfer Done. Closing Driver Sheet...")
    XLDriverWorkBook.Close()
    releaseObject(XLDriverWorkBook)
    releaseObject(XLDriverWorkSheet)
End Sub
```

I'm by no means an expert in VB so please excuse what I can only imagine is very inefficient, and noobish code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Excel error. You must select the sheet, before you select the range:

```
XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A2:D" & rowNum - 1).Copy()

XLAimWorkSheet.Select()                                ' ADDED LINE
XLAimWorkSheet.Range("R2").Select()
XLAimWorkSheet.Range("R2:U" & rowNum - 1).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAllExceptBorders)
```

But also note, `.Select` is not required for [**`PasteSpecial`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) operation. Only needed to move cell cursor.

```
XLDriverWorkSheet.Range("A2:D" & rowNum - 1).Copy()

XLAimWorkSheet.Range("R2:U" & rowNum - 1).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAllExceptBorders)
```